# Calculate values from column having expression

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table "test_calculate" this has a column "CONN_BY" having values

[image]

column can have more than 2 number to multiply and this table may contain millions of rows , I need to get the result of the calculation from "CONN_BY" to "MVP".

I have used xmlquery for the calculation and dynamic query but these are quite slow. Is there another way which is much faster .Please suggest.

Comment: have you tried dynamic query ?

Comment: yes I did. but it is a bit slow. I need something that execute fast.. I mean 10 to 15 sec max (if possible)

Comment: What is the size of dataset, i mean rows you are fetching and how you are executing the query

Answer (score 1):

You can try the dynamic query.

Create a function which returns the calculated value and use it in your insert or select queries.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UFN_CALCULATE (CLM_VALUE VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    RES_VAL NUMBER;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select '||CLM_VALUE||' FROM DUAL' INTO RES_VAL;
    RETURN RES_VAL;
END;
```

You can use that function like below.

```
SELECT UFN_CALCULATE('.0876543 * .09876') FROM DUAL;
SELECT UFN_CALCULATE(CONN_BY) FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `select ... connect by level <= regexp_count(conn_by,'[^*]+')...` query for the implicit cursor within a PL/SQL code block

```
SQL> set serveroutput on 

SQL> declare
  mvp owa.nc_arr; -- numeric array to initialize each multiplication to 1 for each id value
begin
       dbms_output.put_line('ID  MVP'); 
       dbms_output.put_line('--------');       
  for c in
  (
     select id, 
            to_number( regexp_substr(conn_by,'[^*]+',1,level) ) as nr,
            level as lvl , max( level ) over ( partition by id ) as mx_lvl
       from test_calculate
    connect by level <= regexp_count(conn_by,'[^*]+')
        and prior sys_guid() is not null
        and prior conn_by = conn_by
      order by id, lvl  
   )
   loop
    if c.lvl = 1 then mvp(c.id) := 1; end if;
    mvp(c.id) := c.nr * mvp(c.id);
    if c.lvl = c.mx_lvl then
       dbms_output.put_line(c.id||'   '||mvp(c.id)); 
    end if;

   end loop;
end;  
/
```

where `test_calculate` is assumed to have an identity column(`id`)

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=63b06e3a0f000f8b2ae5af476cc62d36)</kbd>